# Permission denied on Parrot Security OS

Tags: permissions, parrot-os

I am trying to install **Metasploit** on **Parrot Security OS** but when I enter the following command:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rapid7/metasploit-omnibus/master/config/templates/metasploit-framework-wrappers/msfupdate.erb > msfinstall && \
  chmod 755 msfinstall && \
  ./msfinstall
```

I get

```
bash: msfinstall: Permission denied.
```

I am currently learning how to use the **OS** and I would be very grateful if you try to help me with fixing it.

Comment: `chmod u+x DOC` neither?

Answer (score 0):

In what folder are you trying to do this? If you are outside of your `home` folder, you need to be `root` or have adequate permissions.

Apart from that, i'm pretty sure you have to be `root` to install metasploit anyway.